Prove the inverse of the statement: The set of all feasible solutions to the LP problem is a convex set.
Let the linear programming problem be represented, in matrix notation, by:
maximize $Z= f(x_1,x_2,\cdots, x_n)=\sum_{j=1}^n  c_jx_j,$ 
subject to:
$AX\leq b, X\geq 0,$
where $Z$ is a scalar, $c$ is a known $(1*n)$ vector. $X= (x_1, x_2,\cdots, x_n)$ an $(n*1)$ vector of unknowns (variables), is a feasible solution (i.e., satisfies both the constraints, and the non-negativity restrictions).
$A$ is a known $(m*n)$ coefficient matrix, and $b$ is a known $(m*1)$ constant column.
Need find the proof for the inverse of the statement:
The set of all feasible solutions to the LP problem is a convex set.

The above statement can be proved by showing that every linear combination of any two feasible solutions is also a feasible solution.
To achieve this, take a set of linear equations, denoted by A, taking any two feasible solutions, let $X_1, X_2.$
Then, have $AX_1\leq b,$ for $X_1\geq 0;$ and $AX_2\leq b,$ for $X_1\geq 0.$
Let $X_3$ be given by the convex linear combination of the two feasible solutions: $X_1, X_2.$ Then,  $X_3 = \alpha X_1 + (1-\alpha)X_2$
where $0\leq \alpha \leq 1.$ Therefore, 
$AX_3 = A[\alpha X_1 + (1-\alpha)X_2] = \alpha A X_1 +  (1-\alpha)AX_2$
Since, $AX_1\leq b,$ and $AX_2\leq b,$ then 
$AX_3 \leq \alpha b + (1-\alpha)b = b$

The inverse of the above statement is:
The set of all infeasible solutions to the LP problem is a concave set.

The inverse statement is attempted to be proved by showing that every linear combination of any two infeasible solutions is also an infeasible solution.
To achieve this, take a set of linear equations, denoted by A, taking any two infeasible solutions, let $X_3, X_4.$
As a infeasible solution would satisfy the non-negativity constraints. 
So, have $AX_3\gt b,$ for $X_3\geq 0;$ and $AX_4\gt b,$ for $X_4\geq 0.$
Let $X_5$ be given by the convex linear combination of the two feasible solutions: $X_3, X_4.$ 
Then, $X_5 = \alpha X_3 + (1-\alpha)X_4$
where $0\leq \alpha \leq 1.$ Therefore, 
$AX_5 = A[\alpha X_3 + (1-\alpha)X_4] = \alpha A X_3 +  (1-\alpha)AX_4$
Since, $AX_3\gt b,$ and $AX_4\gt b,$ then 
$AX_5 \gt \alpha b + (1-\alpha)b = b$


The inverse of the statement "if X is the feasible set of an LP then X is convex" is "if X is convex then X is the feasible set of an LP" and it is not true (at least if you mean finite LPs). It is not clear in what sense you mean the inverse of a statement. Your proof of the first, original statement, is correct, but that's all.

@MichalAdamaszek Seems yours is converse of the first statement. But, if we forget that part; is my proof for the (second) statement (without its link of any sort to the first one) correct? Also, a new question is: why is the converse, as stated by you; not correct. Or, why for $AX = b,$ if $X$ is a convex solution; then it is not the feasible set of an LP?

The second statement is not true.
A simple counterexample is to let $A=I$ and $b$ be a negative vector and thus the set of infeasible solution is $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is convex.
Now, let's take a closer look at your working

The inverse statement is attempted to be proved by showing that every linear combination of any two infeasible solutions is also an infeasible solution.

This is not true as illustrated in the following picture where some convex combination of infeasible solution is feasible.


a infeasible solution would satisfy the non-negativity constraints.

Why would that be so? this is not true. An infeasible solution can violate the nonnegative constraint.
Also, notice that the set of infeasible solution can be convex as well. For example when $n=1$, if the feasible set is the set nonnegative number, then the infeasible solution is just the set of negative number which is convex.
